# ES6 modules in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

To my big surprise the following trivial line:

```
export const PI = 3.14;
```

does not compile in Visual Studio Code and I am getting the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export const PI = 3.14;                                                  

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could do you please explain what do you mean by is not running on Visual Studio Code

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher he means the code doesnt compile

Comment: Hmm , are you using the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Comment: Code never really compiles "in VS Code", it compiles in some compiler which is run by VS Code based on your configuration. You'll need to explain what compiler settings you are using.

Comment: Exactly, I am using Code Runner Extension

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper this extension uses nodes to run the code , nodejs uses CommonJs Module syntax so the follwoing will work `module.exports.PI = 3.14;
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using ES6 Module syntax.and `node.js` env which does not support ES6 Module syntax.
NodeJS uses CommonJS Module syntax `module.exports` not ES6 module syntax `export` keyword.

Solutions:

1. Use babel npm package to transpile your ES6 to a commonjs target
2. Refactor with CommonJS syntax.

Comment: That means VS Code does not support ES6 module syntax?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper this extension uses nodejs to run the code, nodejs uses CommonJs Module syntax so the following will work `module.exports.PI = 3.14;`

Comment: Is there any other extension as to run ES6 syntax?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Sorry I am not aware of any, but if you are just trying to test some code written on Es6, use chrome console, it supports this natively

Answer (score 1):

To use ES6 Export module do you need add some transpiler to you project, if you don't want static type checker you can use Babel but if you want work with types in JS I recommend you use TypeScript.